# htmlagilitypack link.attributes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, console, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

**Sorry for the duplicate but this one seemed different.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace GetLinks
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
HtmlDocument doc = new     
HtmlWeb().Load("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language&#8221");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
{
Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
Console.WriteLine(link.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
Console.ReadKey();
}
}
```

}

**So i'm using htmlagilitypack and I got the error on:**

```
Console.WriteLine(link.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

**And this is the error message:**

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=ConsoleApplication2
  StackTrace:
   at GetLinks.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

**How would one go about trying to fix these things? I tried creating an object instance and that didn't work.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to access a property from null value object, So all what you need is to check whether it's OK before proceeding your code

change that line to

```
var href=link.Attributes["href"];
if (href!=null) Console.WriteLine(href.Value);
```

I hope it'll help.